# How to get Playlist ID on search: list (playlist type)

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

i'm stuck on my app development: i'm trying to get the Playlist ID on a youtube search list (i'm searching for playlists). I am looking at the youtube api site and on the test site it comes with playlist id. On my app, i do the same, but i don't get the ID, or i'm not seeing it on my "item" on the iterated code.

I know that currently is searching for video ID and it is not correct. I've tried so far:

```
item.id
item.getId().getPlaylistId()
item.getId().playlistId
```

also entirely iniside item.

I let you my async task code:

```
SearchListResponse searchResponse;
    try {
        YouTube.Search.List search = mYouTubeDataApi.search().list("id,snippet");

        search.setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
        search.setQ(mTitle);

        search.setType("playlist");

        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
        search.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS);
        searchResponse = search.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    if (searchResponse == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList videoIds = new ArrayList();

    for (SearchResult item : searchResponse.getItems()) {
        //this is what i was talking about. My search result item
        //is not showing me any playlist id
        videoIds.add(item.getId().getVideoId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've already figured it out by paying attention to my own code.

The data received is setted by the fields:

`search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");`

i was missing the id/playlistId on my search, so i added it:
                `search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,id/playlistId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");`

Now i'm getting my playlist id (and a lot of other info i did not need).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The best way to get the list of playlists is to use [`search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) request. 
You will have to specify `type=playlist` and the title of the video for the `q` parameter.

`Search:list` will gives you the result that match the query parameters specified in your request. You can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

Note that this may not give you the playlists you're expecting if the title of the video isn't specific enough.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=VIDEO_TITLE_HERE&type=playlist&key=API_KEY_HERE
```

Comment: Hi! i'm currently getting the list of playlists, but i can't retrieve the playlist ID for each SearchResult on the search. I got no problem to get video ids if i use type=video
Maybe it has to do with this?
`YouTube.Search.List search = mYouTubeDataApi.search().list("id,snippet");`

or this?:
`search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");`
Thanks for your answer!